# Back-up of SQL Server Database to network writable location fails

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, sqlcmd

I want to make a backup of SQL Sever database. Using **sqlcmd** I am able to direct output to a shared folder on my local machine. I can make a back-up to a location on the server but I cannot direct the back-up file to the location on my local machine (shared folder).
That is in sqlcmd:

```
BACKUP DATABASE <dbname> TO DISK 'c:\Temp\dbname.bak';
Go
```

works

```
:out \\path\to\shared\location\msg.out
SELECT 1;
```

also works and creates a file with the select's output.

```
BACKUP DATABASE <dbname> TO DISK = '\\path\to\shared\location\db.bak';
```

Fails with:

> Cannot open backup device '\path\to\shared\location\db.bak'. Operating system error 53(The network path was not found.).
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server <xxxx\xxxx>, Line 1

Any idea why the backup fails?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have access to the share path? I *assume*, also, that the SQL Server account is a domain account? A local service account will be unable to access remote paths.

Comment: In your example the `:out` works because the connection to the target path is made by your locally logged on account; the SQL Server backup connection is made by the SQL Server service account user.

Comment: @Stu The shared folder is set to allow 'everyone' to read/write to it.

Comment: @Marked what about the NTFS permissions, they both need to permit the SQL Server account.

Comment: @ThomA unfortunately I current don't have access to the server to verify accounts. I will check with our IT guys

Comment: @Stu NTFS permissions: Full Control

Comment: Is there a firewall on the SQL Server that needs ports opening for SMB network share? 145 I think, you'll need to check.

Comment: Even if it's set to "everyone" a local service account won't be able to access to share as it will attempt the authenticate anonymously.

Comment: "Everyone" on most AD setups only includes authenticated accounts. A local service account is only valid for a single machine, it cannot authenticate on the network to the domain controller. While you could in theory allow Guest as well, that's rather dangerous The only *correct* way to do this is to either make SQL Server use a domain account (maybe a gMSA) or to write it to a local drive and copy it in a separate batch.